spring security 3 and actuator/prometheus
i`m trying to configure prometheus in my app with springSecurity
i do this config
management:
  server:
      port: 9090
  security:
      enabled: false
  endpoint:
    prometheus:
        enabled: true
    health:
        enabled: true
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: prometheus,health
  metrics:
    distribution:
        percentiles-histogram:
            "[http.server.requests]": true
  prometheus:
    metrics:
      export:
          enabled: true

and config security
authorizeHttpRequests {
                    it.requestMatchers("/api/actuator/**").permitAll()
                    it.requestMatchers("/api/actuator").permitAll()

but still 401

It seems that you have not configured the management prefix URL. The default is: /actuator/**
If you want to change that default you have to set
management.endpoints.web.base-path
according to the documentation
